# Find local maxima or peaks(index) in a numeric series using numpy and pandas Peak refers to the values surrounded by smaller values on both sides

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

Write a python program to find all the local maxima or peaks(index) in a numeric series using numpy and pandas Peak refers to the values surrounded by smaller values on both sides

Note

Create a Pandas series from the given input.

Input format:

First line of the input consists of list of integers separated by spaces to from pandas series.

Output format:

Output display the array of indices where peak values present.

Sample testcase

input1
12 1 2 1 9 10 2 5 7 8 9 -9 10 5 15

output1
[2 5 10 12]

[smapletest cases image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaJRD.png)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
data = [12, 1, 2, 1.1, 9, 10, 2.1, 5, 7, 8, 9.1, -9, 10.1, 5.1, 15]
s = pd.Series(data)

n = 3  # number of points to be checked before and after

from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

local_max_index = argrelextrema(s.to_frame().to_numpy(), np.greater_equal, order=n)[0].tolist()
print (local_max_index)
[0, 5, 14]

local_max_index = s.index[(s.shift() <= s) & (s.shift(-1) <= s)].tolist()
print (local_max_index)
[2, 5, 10, 12]

local_max_index = s.index[s == s.rolling(n, center=True).max()].tolist()
print (local_max_index)
[2, 5, 10, 12]
```

EDIT: Solution for processing value in DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Input': ["12 1 2 1 9 10 2 5 7 8 9 -9 10 5 15"]})
print (df)
                                Input
0  12 1 2 1 9 10 2 5 7 8 9 -9 10 5 15

s = df['Input'].iloc[[0]].str.split().explode().astype(int).reset_index(drop=True)
print (s)
0     12
1      1
2      2
3      1
4      9
5     10
6      2
7      5
8      7
9      8
10     9
11    -9
12    10
13     5
14    15
Name: Input, dtype: int32

local_max_index = s.index[(s.shift() <= s) & (s.shift(-1) <= s)].tolist()
print (local_max_index)
[2, 5, 10, 12]

df['output'] = [local_max_index]
print (df)
                                Input          output
0  12 1 2 1 9 10 2 5 7 8 9 -9 10 5 15  [2, 5, 10, 12]
```

Comment: Input and output use space-separated pandas series. I also attach the ss of sample testcase in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

a = "12 1 2 1 9 10 2 5 7 8 9 -9 10 5 15"
a = [int(x) for x in a.split(" ")]

angles = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i!=0:
        if a[i]>a[i-1]:
            angles.append('rise')
        else:
            angles.append('fall')
    else:
        angles.append('ignore')
prev=0
prev_val = "none"
counts = []
for s in angles:
    if s=="fall" and prev_val=="rise":
        prev_val = s
        counts.append(1)
    else:
        prev_val = s
        counts.append(0)

peaks_pd = pd.Series(counts).shift(-1).fillna(0).astype(int)
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'a':a,
     'peaks':peaks_pd
     })

peak_vals = list(df[df['peaks']==1]['a'].index)
```

This could be improved further. Steps I have followed:

1. First find the angle whether its rising or falling
2. Look at the index at which it starts falling after rising and call it as peaks

Comment: Input must be in a space-separated format to pass the test cases. I also add ss in questions

Comment: Modified the answer for input